# which one is the better static program analysis tool for objective C

Tags: objective-c, static-code-analysis

I need to check my code has follwed a standard coding guidlines like naming conventaion or unused code etc for objective C.
If you guys used any such tool then how effcient they are and how was your experience while using those?

thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW we use PCLint with MISRA ruleset but for coding guidelines we have code reviews before checking following a normal written guideline.

Comment: The default LLVM/Clang static analyser is very high quality.

Comment: but if we are done with the initial code review by setting the rules then we can spend more time in checking the code quality rather than spending time on checking the coding guidelines.

Comment: TBH: You shouldn't be merging code into the codebase that doesn't follow the guidelines, so, as you point out, you can work on code quality over correctness.